# Update hibernate entity with list

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to update entity in hibernate, like

```
class EntityA {
private String name

//one-to-many, orhpan removal = true, bidirectioanl
private List<EntityB> listB;
}
```

I recieve the object from REST API, and I need to update item in the listB and name for Entity A.

Items in the list can be updated/removed/added

What is the best practice to this, from hibernate perpective ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is what is the format of representation resources which you invoking using http request.

- JSON
- XML

If your resource format is json then you gonna map json object to your java object and manage it with JPA.

**Example** **:**

Lets say your json format resource contain following user data called user_info.json

```
{ 
  "firstName" : "jack",
  "lastName"  : "Dawson",
  "contacts" : [
                {
                  "cellphone" : "434343",
                  "address" : "agrabad",
                  "city"  : "ctg"
                },
                {
                  "cellphone" : "+88667755",
                  "address" : "chokbazar",
                  "city"  : "dhk"
                 }
               ]
      }
```

And your user pojo class is :

```
public class User {

Private String firstName;
Private String lastName;
private Collection<Contact> contacts;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public Collection<Contact> getContacts() {
    return contacts;
}
public void setContacts(Collection<Contact> contacts) {
    this.contacts = contacts;
}
}
```

There is lot of json lib, i personally prefer Gson developed by Google.
So using Gson you can map json object to java object. Following code snippet about mapping json to java object :

```
User user = new Gson().fromJson("user_info_Json_String", User.class)
```

So you have done with mapping. All you have to do execute user object according to EntityManager operation.

**Note:** User class state has to match json key string during mapping.

If resource format is XML then JAXB is great feature for marshalling and unmarshalling e.g object to xml and vice-versa.

**Update :** To update collection of contacts to database we don't need to add element one by one. Java Collection has method call addAll(). Just using it . Here is the example :

```
Collection<Contacts> jsonUserContacs = user.getContacts();
Collection<Contacts> dbContacts = dbuser.getContacts();
dbContacts.addAll(jsonUserContacs);
```

Thats it. You don't need to add contact one by one.

Hope This knowledge transfer helps you. Thanks.

Comment: But my question was how to update the entity inside database? should I get all List of all elements and update one by one?

Comment: No .. you don't need to element one by one to db collection. I just updated mine answer.

Comment: but what if inside contact something changed? And I need to update it

Comment: fetch particular contact from db then update that db contact with json data then merge that updated contact to db.